# datepicker not working when colorbox iframe load for second time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker, colorbox

I have a page **tblContFrdmCapitatedProviders.aspx** having an anchor tag

```
<a id="aAdd" class="aAdd" href="tblContFrdmCapitatedProvidersAdd.aspx">Add</a>
```

when i click the href addr will show up in a colorbox iframe.

here is the js code

```
$(function ($) {

$(".aAdd").colorbox({ Width: "60%", Height: "260px" });
```

});

**tblContFrdmCapitatedProviders.aspx** having a master page in which the  base jquery files are referenced.

And in **tblContFrdmCapitatedProvidersAdd.aspx** there is another masterpage, also contain the references to Jquery base files. In this page i have 2 textbox with jquery datepicker bound to it.

```
$(function ($) {

        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
```

Now the problem part.

When we 1st click the "Add" the iframe show and the datepicker is properly shown. Now when we close the iframe and click "Add" for the second time, iframe comes but the datepicker inside wont work.After that how many time we click "Add" datepicker wont come. If we reload the parent page, then it works for the first time.

what i miss????

**EDIT 1**

aspx code for **tblContFrdmCapitatedProvidersAdd.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Freedom/AddMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="tblContFrdmCapitatedProvidersAdd.aspx.cs" Inherits="Contestation.Freedom.tblContFrdmCapitatedProvidersAdd" %>
```

```
<script>
    $(function ($) {

        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });

</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="pageheader-pop">Capitated Providers</div>
        <div>
            <table class="table-list-pop" style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Capitated Providers</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCapProv" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCapProv" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>

                <td>Provider ID</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProviderID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Plan Number</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlanNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>IPA Name</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtIPAName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Plan Name</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlanName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>From Date</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFromDate" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFromDate" ErrorMessage="Invalid date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>To Date</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Width="128px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtToDate" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtToDate" ErrorMessage="Invalid date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>

                <td>Speciality Name</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpecName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Speciality Fund</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpecFund" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="dv-controls-pop">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btnsave-pop" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that function for datepicker is executed when you load iframe second time?

Comment: i add an alert in document.ready and it is calling every time i click "Add" .

Comment: can you show us the textbox code in asp.net page

Comment: i edited the post and added the aspx page codes